# Jest - mock fat arrow function within React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

Given my component and test below, why does my `confirmClickHandler` method still get called when I run my test?

Note: I noticed that when I change the method from a fat arrow function to just a regular function, it gets mocked out correctly.   What am I missing here?

```
class CalendarConfirmation extends React.Component {
  ...

  confirmClickHandler = (e) =>  {
  ...
  }
}
```

and my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import CalendarConfirmation from '../components/CalendarConfirmation';

describe('Test CalendarConfirmation', () => {
  let calendarConfirmation;
  calendarConfirmation = mount (<CalendarConfirmation />);
  calendarConfirmation.instance().confirmClickHandler = jest.fn();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, would have liked to know how you figured this out if you did.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'

class Foo extends React.Component {
  // babel transpiles this too Foo.prototype.canMock
  protoMethod () {
    // will be mocked
  }

  // this becomes an instance property
  instanceMethod = () => {
    return 'NOT be mocked'
  }

  render () {
    return (<div>{`${this.protoMethod()} ${this.instanceMethod()}`}</div>)
  }
}

Foo.prototype.protoMethod = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('you shall')

it('should be mocked', () => {
  const mock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('be mocked')
  const wrapper = mount(<Foo />)
  wrapper.instance().instanceMethod = mock
  wrapper.update()
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Note however, that this fails when using `shallow` instead of mount.

Comment: this did not work for me i am using create react  and enzyme-adapter-react-16

Comment: test failed with "Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called."

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything.

> Jest can only mock the structure of objects that are present at
>   require time. It does it by reflection (not by analysis), which means
>   that properties that get added by the constructor cannot be mocked.
>   It's important to understand though that a fat-arrow assignment in a
>   class in JS is not a class method; it's a class property holding a
>   reference to a function.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6065